# Create intervals in a sorted array

Tags: java, intervals, sortedlist

Let's say I have a sorted array of `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 21, 23, 25, 26}`.
I'd like to put these elements into intervals the following way:

```
1..5
7..10
15..16
21..21
23..23
25..26
```

In reality I have much bigger data, so I would need an algorithm with a good runtime.

What I had in mind is the following:
Separate the array into 2 parts, and with 4 loops go through the array. One loop from 0 index, 2 loop from middle of array and 1 loop from the end of it. Every loop would check if the current and the next element's diff is 1, if yes, then go to next element, else create an interval from previous elements and start a new interval from the next element.

My question is that is it a good approach, or is there a better way? Please pseudo or java code.

Comment: Why not just start with index 0 and do sequential loop and keep track of the interval's first element.

Comment: How do you derive the intervals? I don't see any pattern in it.

Comment: Why all the loops?  It seems like a single loop, with a new interval starting when last value  + 1 != current value.

Comment: Are the intervals given to you? Are you trying to write a function that takes `int[] originalArray` and `int[][] intervals` (where `intervals[i].length == 2` for all `i < intervals.length`) as parameters? Please clarify on what data types are given as inputs and what data type is expected as an output. Also, did you try to write a method to do this yet? Can you share what you've done?

Comment: @Blake int[] array is the input, with numbers from 000006 to 999999. Output could be int[][]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear solution:

```
int intervalStart = a[0];
for (int i = 1; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if (a[i] > a[i-1] + 1) {
        outputInterval(intervalStart, a[i-1]);
        intervalStart = a[i];
    }
}
outputInterval(intervalStart, a[a.length-1]);
```

Runnable version: https://ideone.com/NZ2Uex

Answer (score 1):

You could consider having an array of [IntRange](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html)s from Apache Commons to represent such a concept.

Yes, it requires a 3rd-party library, but it's Apache Commons, after all.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get the lists of consecutive integers.

The simplest and most naive way in **O(n)** is to do something like this :

```
List<List<Integer>> list_of_sublists = new List<>(); // The list of sublists
int lastElement = elements[0];
List<Integer> subList = new List <>(); // The current sublist
subList.add(lastElement);
int i = 1; // We start with index 1 because index 0 is already done
while (i < elements.length){
   int element = elements[i]
   if !(lastElement + 1 == element)){ //If not a consecutive we start a new list
       list_of_sublists.add(subList);
       subList = new List<>();
   }
   lastElement = element;
   subList.add(element);
   i ++;

//We didn't add the last sublist
list_of_sublists.add(subList);
return list_of_sublists;
```

You can easily adapt to `arrays` by getting the intervals and copying afterwars each interval.

Answer (score 0):

Another version, with two pointers (python):

```py
def compress_to_range(vector):
    # O(n) in time, just one pass thru the list
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(vector):
        j = i+1
        while j < len(vector) and vector[j] == vector[j-1]+1:
            j += 1
        # j now points to the element outside the interval
        result.append([vector[i], vector[j-1]])
        i = j

    return result
```